# flutter asset image does not unload until initiated? how to fix this?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Hi I am new to flutter development. I have used a asset image in the container for mobile application. Initially image size was 5mb thought due to its size image load in 2-3 seconds. later decreased image size but this did not fix the issue. How can I fix this issue? I used 3 images in ListView. when i swipe between them images take around 2-3 seconds to load. Thanks in advance.

```
final PageController ctrl = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8);

class PageViewContent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PageViewContentState createState() => _PageViewContentState();
}

class _PageViewContentState extends State<PageViewContent> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView(
      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      controller: ctrl,
      children: <Widget>[
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home3()));
          },
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              AnimatedContainer(
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                curve: Curves.easeOutQuint,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, bottom: 80, right: 30),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/med.jpg'),
                    )),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, right: 35, bottom: 20),
                child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Text(
                      'Medicine Requests',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey[700],
                          fontSize: 30,
                          fontFamily: 'Barlow'),
                    )),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
//            print('pressed 1');
            Navigator.push(
                context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home1()));
          },
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              AnimatedContainer(
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                curve: Curves.easeOutQuint,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, bottom: 80, right: 30),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/heart.jpg'),
                    )),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, right: 35, bottom: 20),
                child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Text(
                      'Plasma Requests',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey[700],
                          fontSize: 36,
                          fontFamily: 'Barlow'),
                    )),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home2()));
          },
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              AnimatedContainer(
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                curve: Curves.easeOutQuint,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, bottom: 80, right: 30),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/hands.jpg'),
                    )),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, right: 35, bottom: 20),
                child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Text(
                      'Plasma Donors',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey[700],
                          fontSize: 36,
                          fontFamily: 'Barlow'),
                    )),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what extension is the image? please add some code snippets to make it more clear and allow contributors to help.

Comment: "AnimatedContainer(
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                curve: Curves.easeOutQuint,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, bottom: 80, right: 30),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/med.jpg'),
                    )),
              ),"

here is the code. image extension is jpg. I have 2 other containers

Comment: Please put all code in your post. Dont use comments for code.

Comment: try using a different image and see the behavior, i don't see an issue with the syntaxt. if this doesnt work, look at precached image docs

Comment: I am still a beginner and not able to properly implement precache image in my app. Your help is really appreciated. I could not understand how to use asset image as a precache image. there are plenty of tutorials on network image.

Comment: emulator or device? debug mode is slow, try testing in profile mode or release mode.

Comment: Device in debug mode. I will try release build. Thank you.

Comment: profile mode is ~95% the speed of release build without the hassle of manually installing the app. Both require a physical device. Furthermore I have seen the debug mode in physical device is painfully slow. I am using debug mode on emulator with SSD. It is as fast as native app or the equivalent of release mode in actual device